# If THING's URL is Empty then Remove Thing?

Tags: jquery, url, background-image, this, removeclass

Forgive me that my GoogleFu is weak.

I'm running a check to see if the user has added a background image for their post. If they haven't then the background-image ULR will be empty.

```
background-image();
```

Ive got this coded, and it IS detecting the empty URL (IE: the alert goes off).

I also understand WHY it doesn't work. As it's part of the THEN and not the IF the "this" doesn't know what it refers to.

Thing is, I've been coding jQuery for a few months, but don't know a BETTER/PROPER way to do it.

```
if ( $('.postImage').css('background-image', 'url()') ){
    alert("EMPTY!!!");
    $(this).remove();
};
```

Why not just code it like this?

```
$(.postImage).remove();
```

Well because there may be more than one of these on a page, and we only want to affect the ones that are empty.

Teach me, oh greybeards, how would you handle this (in a simple and elegant fashion, without bloated code)?

**::EDIT::**

Alright, it's been some time but this is what I have.

```
   $('.postImage').each( function(){
        if ( $(this).css('background-image', 'url()') ){

            alert("EMPTY!!!");

            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        };
    });
```

Problem is, this affects anything that has the .postImage class. Even if it has something like 'url(image/logo.png)', it sees that is has the 'url()' attribute and applies this. It doesn't seem to care what is IN that attribute.

So, on my front page, I am getting this EMPTY!!! alter 9 times, and I can watch, one at a time, as it targets each object that is part of the .postImage class, and removes it's background-image.

Comment: Use jQuery to get all elements that match a certain rule, then remove each of them in a loop.

Comment: Might want to give $.filter() a shot too. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

you have to navigate using `each` to do this kind of task.
like...

```
$('.postImage').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).css('background-image', 'url()') ){
        alert("EMPTY!!!");
        $(this).remove();
    };
});
```

but I believe you can also do

```
$('.postImage').css('background-image', 'url()').remove()
```

if you are not planning to any alerting when removing.

Comment: I'll try the each method, and report back.

As far as I know, 

    $('.postImage').css('background-image', 'url()').remove()

would try and set the css to be blank, and then remove it. 

I am ignorant in that?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
if ($('#myDiv').css("background-image") === 'url()') {
    alert("Empty Background!");
}
```

});